# How to Set the instance Variables after initialising a class in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

The constructor :

```
def  __init__(self,name,height,race):
    self.name = name
    self.height = height
    self.race = race



n = Student("John")
n.set_height(190)
n.set_race("Black")
```

when I do this I get an error that says Student.**init**() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'height' and 'race'

Comment: Set a default for or remove the arguments from the `__init__` method that are not required? If an instance can be initialised without those parameters, why are they required by your initialiser?

Answer (score 0):

If you ask in the `constructor(__init__())` function for 3 parameters, you must give all 3.
So you can use: `n = Student("Jhon", 190, "Black")`
OR

```
def  __init__(self,name):
    self.name = name

def set_height(height):
    self.height = height

def set_race(race):
    self.race = race



n = Student("John")
n.set_height(190)
n.set_race("Black")
```

Here you set only the name in the constructor and then set the other values using `set` functions.

These methods must be defined inside the `class` and they will be used to initialize the properties `height` and `race`. If you don't call these methods, your object will not have values for them.

The way you defnied the constructor works too, but you must to pass all values you're asking in between `()`. Those values are used to initialize the properties

Comment: I defined the setters in the class

Comment: Yes, but you also asked for `3` parameters in the `constructor` definition. You can also have the `setters`  defioined in the class and the parameters in the cconstructor, but when you call the constructor, you must pass all parameters you're asking for in the declaration

Comment: There are 2 ways to make it work. `1.` You delete `height` and `race` from `__init__`. `2.` you keep them but you initialize the class like this: `n = Student("Jhon", 190, "Black")`. Then you can use the `setters` to change the values, but you must use those parameters